# Splitting string into tuple

Tags: string, python-2.7, tuples, type-conversion

Given a string in this format: "Here is some random text, like 5/4=3./12/3/4", so "Again some spaces\n/12/12/12" would count as well... I have to convert this into a four part tuple, such as (12,3,4,"Here is some random text, like 5/4=3") where the first three numbers are made into integers. how would I go about doing this using split and slicing?

Comment: and i have to write this into a function as well

Comment: strings like "Here is some random text, like 5/4=3./12/3/4as", "Here is some random text, like 5/4=3/12/412/a/3/4" and " Here is some spaces 12/32/4" would print None since they do not follow the format or contain non-integer types in the last three slots

Comment: split() by `/` to get a list of string, then return the last 3 element of the list, and join() rest of the string with `/`